# How to put cookie consent in theme js?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using a theme for my website with its own javascript. I tried to put a cookie consent in the available js but it is disabling the whole javascript. How do I do it?

Available js for analytics

```
 if ( page.defaults.googleAnalyticsId ) {
         (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
         (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
         })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

         ga('create', page.defaults.googleAnalyticsId, 'auto');
         ga('send', 'pageview');
       }
```

The way I tried.

```
 if ( page.defaults.googleAnalyticsId ) {
<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="tracking" >
         (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
         (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
         })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
         ga('create', page.defaults.googleAnalyticsId, 'auto');
         ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
       }
```

Comment: what is that `cookie-consent="tracking"` thing is? i cant see it on the [w3 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-script-element.html). is it some js plugin you used? could you provide [mcve]? and you cant mix `<script>` with javascript `if`, hence your js broke down.

Comment: Cookie consent tracking is for asking user their consent if they want to be tracked or not by google analytics. Will it work if script is written outside the if. You can check it out here (https://www.termsfeed.com/cookie-consent/)